# How to put a line break between the label and the title of a theorem created with `newmdtheoremenv`?

Tags: mdframed, newtheorem

I want to put a line break between "Text 1" and "This is the title" (see figure).

[image: Text 1.]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{textSty}{font=\small,backgroundcolor=green!10, linewidth=0pt, innerleftmargin=3ex, innerrightmargin=3ex, innertopmargin=3ex, innerbottommargin=3ex, innermargin=+0.5cm, outermargin =+0.5cm}
\newcounter{textCounter}
\newmdtheoremenv[style=textSty]{myText}[textCounter]{Text}
\begin{document}
    \begin{myText}
      \begin{center}
        \textsc{This is the title} \\
        \textit{This is the author}  
      \end{center}
  This is the text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. 
    \end{myText}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add `\hfill` at the begin of the `myText`-environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{textSty}{
    font=\small,
    backgroundcolor=green!10,
    linewidth=0pt,
    innerleftmargin=3ex,
    innerrightmargin=3ex,
    innertopmargin=3ex,
    innerbottommargin=3ex,
    innermargin=+0.5cm,
    outermargin =+0.5cm,
}
\newcounter{textCounter}
\newmdtheoremenv[style=textSty]{myText}[textCounter]{Text}
\begin{document}
    \begin{myText}
        \hfill % <- NEW
        \begin{center}
            \textsc{This is the title} \\
            \textit{This is the author}
        \end{center}
        This is the text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text.
    \end{myText}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Leonardo Castro If you are satisfied with the solution, please consider accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark ✓, see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows others that the question is solved and will remove it from the list of unanswered questions.